# How can i convert this SQL into an LINQ syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

The schema is like

[image]

The SQL query with the results needed is as follows

```
SELECT   dbo.Products.*
FROM     dbo.ProductManufacturers INNER JOIN
         dbo.Products ON dbo.ProductManufacturers.ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID INNER JOIN
         dbo.Manufacturers ON dbo.ProductManufacturers.ManufacturerID = dbo.Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
WHERE    (dbo.ProductManufacturers.ManufacturerID = 1)
```

How can i have the same results with LINQ?

Comment: you are using ef lnq to entities?

Comment: Can you show your model classes?

Comment: If you have proper foreign keys and lazy loading it would be as simple as `context.ProductManufacturers.First(x => x.ManufacturerId == 1)`

Comment: @johnny5 Into the spot. The following does the trick
Products = db.Manufacturers.Where(t => t.ManufacturerID == id).SelectMany(s => s.Products);

Comment: @OrElse that will return you an IQueryable, I'm assuming you want to .ToList() that afterwards, but if you knew then why did you ask the question?

Comment: @johnny5 If i knew the answer i would not capture the schema in image, open it with paint edit it and so on.. I simply got inspired by your comment. If you could also post it as an answer, i would love to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the foreign keys are set up then something Like this should work:

```
db.Manufacturers.Where(t => t.ManufacturerID == id)
                .SelectMany(s => s.Products)
                .ToList();
```